# <Error>: DevanagariSangamMN: FT_Load_Glyph failed: error 6

Tags: ios4

i m getting error ": DevanagariSangamMN: FT_Load_Glyph failed: error 6."when i m trying to login in facebook from my iphone app.and it is not going in any of request succeed function,i m facing this prob from last 2 days so please give eme suggestion if anything is possible,
thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Have you got any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I think  it came from the FreeType library

You may Check This [link.](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-base_interface.html#FT_Load_Glyph)

Comment: You Can Also Look at this tutorial by RayWenderlich for more Details http://www.raywenderlich.com/1578/how-to-get-a-user-profile-with-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app